# Disable Back Home button Android 3.1

Tags: android, back-button, android-3.1-honeycomb

I have an application running on Samsung Galaxy Tab 8.9 with Android 3.1.

I have to disable Back button. I know that

`<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />`

disables the Home button. But I don't want to disable the Home button. I want to disable **only** the BackButton and not the HomeButton.

Thanks everyone..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override onBackPressed in your activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply override onBackPressed() like this:

```
@override
public void onBackPressed(){}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your activity to override the BackButton :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // whatever you want to do when the BackButton is pressed.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override 
public boolean onKeyDown(int iKeyCode, KeyEvent event)
{

    if(iKeyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK || iKeyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) 
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```